# Is php notice will stop php execution?

Tags: php, warnings, notice

I have defined a constant twice in a php application. It gives a notice. But my app execution stopped. Is it possible to stop execution on php notice?

Comment: No, execution never stops on `Notices`.

Comment: It may hamper other behaviour, but not execution (unless a specifically crafted error handler made it so). Go into more detail about your observations. Also see [mcve].

Comment: A constant should be just that: constant. It's value cannot change during execution, but could be re-declared or re-defined before it is used elsewhere in the code, although it shouldn't be (hence the notice). The later declaration should take precedence over the first, but there really isn't a good reason to re-declare a constant.

Comment: not directly, however it can cause a cascade of errors that may or may not stop execution and or break other things.  An example is an undefined array index which can cause all kinds of issues in other parts of code, but is still just a notice.

Comment: Further, to fix this you can/may be able to do `if(!defined('YOUR_CONST')) define('YOUR_CONST', 'foo');`